# Why does this statement throw a typescript error?

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

The following statement throws a type error. Why?

```
const x: Chat = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
```

The error is:

> Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Chat': message, name, createdAt  ts(2739)

The spread operand provides three elements of the object, and the id is provided by the second operand.

I am using Vue 3.0.0, firebase 9.0.2 and typescript 4.1.5

here is the whole component:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore, Timestamp } from '@/firebase/config'
// import Chat from '@/types/Chat'

interface Chat {
  id?: string
  message: string
  name: string | null
  createdAt: Timestamp
}

import {
  collection as collect,
  query,
  orderBy,
  onSnapshot,
} from 'firebase/firestore'

const getCollection = (collection: string) => {
  const documents = ref<Chat[]>()
  const error = ref<string>()
  try {
    const q = query(
      collect(projectFirestore, collection),
      orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    )
    const unsubscripe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const results: Chat[] = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const x: Chat = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
        doc.data().createdAT && results.push(x)
      })
      documents.value = results
    })
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof Error) {
      error.value = err.message
    } else {
      throw Error('Unknown Error')
    }
  }
  return { documents, error }
}

export default getCollection
```

I am new to typescript, but this does seem strange. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error tells you that the type TypeScript has for `doc.data()` doesn't provide the missing properties. That's probably because TypeScript just doesn't know what the type is, or has the wrong type. There doesn't seem to be any type information near `doc.data()` -- `doc` has no type annotation, `querySnapshot` has no type annotations, and `onSnapshot` has no type annotations. I suspect `onSnapshot` is a generic function that defaults its generic type parameter that would provide a specific type for `querySnapshot` (and in turn for `doc`), but I don't use Firebase. That's where I'd look.

Comment: If you hover over `doc.data()`, your IDE will probably tell you what type TypeScript thinks it returns.

Comment: Note that `doc.data().createdAT` will always be `undefined` because your field is actually `createdAt`. Try to avoid overtyping and use [`withConverter()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query.md#querywithconverter_2) and a [`FirestoreDataConverter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter) to perform your type assertions instead. Also don't forget to return the unsubscribe function of the listener back to the caller and you should also add an error handling callback on `onSnapshot`.

Comment: Thanks - I am going with teh Type Assertuion suggested below.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman. I am trying to learnTypescript and Firebase.Firestore, and also using these in a Vue 3 app that I am building as an exercise from a YouTube based course, which used firebase v8 while I am using v9. Proving challenging, but interesting. You comments are greatly appreciated and I will look into the Converters that you mention. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@TJCrowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) commented, you can check what the [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot#documentsnapshotdata) method returns. It returns object of type `DocumentData` and Typescript doesn't really know what the contents are. You can try using a type assertion like this and specify that the object will be of type `Chat`:

```
const x = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as Chat
```

However, this can lead to mistyping documents that don't exist (when `doc.exists === false` - usually found when working with a `DocumentReference` rather than queries). Instead of asserting the type on the line with `doc.data()`, you can assert the type of the `CollectionReference` that you used in the query instead. This works the same for a `DocumentReference` too. Typescript will make sure that you've properly handled the case where a document doesn't exist first.

```
collect(projectFirestore, collection) as CollectionReference<Chat>
// ...

// x will be a Chat object when `doc.exists === true` (which it is in queries)
const x = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
```

You can read more about `Type Assertion` in Typescript's [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

Comment: Thanks. Using a type assertion works, and is sufficient for now. I was missunderstanding the message, but now I get it. It is interesting that this was supposed to be a generic component, but that is far less simple with typescript. I can either import each Type and test which type I am retrieving before Asserting, or use Any which defeats the purpose. I will need to give that some thought.

Comment: @maxweld if you know which docs you are fetching you know the type so seems pretty okay to use type assertion

Comment: @maxweld Related to how I mentioned using a `FirestoreDataConverter`, you can spoof the CollectionReference into thinking that you've used one using `CollectionReference<DataType>` and `DocumentReference<DataType>`. While you can do this, make sure that the types are what you expect from Firestore (e.g. your custom type might have a Date object but Firestore sent a Timestamp object). I've added this information to Dharmaraj's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @samthecodingman. I just considered the QuerySnapshot case where all documents matched exists ‍♂️